# How to insert a attribute into a doc just if it does not exist?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to insert a attribute into a doc called 'users' using bulk on python.

Like this:

> ```
>     actions = [
>         {
>             '_op_type': 'update',
>             "_index": index,
>             "_type": "users",
>             "_id": s['id_user'],
>             "doc": {
>                 "purchases": []
>             },
>         }
>         for i, s in users.iterrows()
>     ]
>     success, failure = self.db.bulk(actions, stats_only=True)
> ```

How can I add purchases just if it does not exist? I do not want a upsert in this case. It's forbidden to change the value if it has already been indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do it using a scripted upsert, like this:

```
actions = [
    {
        '_op_type': 'update',
        "_index": index,
        "_type": "users",
        "_id": s['id_user'],
        "script": {
          "source": "ctx._source.purchases = ctx._source.purchases ?: params.purchases",
          "params": {
            "purchases": []
          }
        },
        "scripted_upsert": true,
        "upsert": {}
    }
    for i, s in users.iterrows()
]
success, failure = self.db.bulk(actions, stats_only=True)
```

The `purchases` array will only get assigned with the array in `params` if not already defined in the source.

Comment: Awesome! Thank u!